# How can I create a tuple where each of the members are compared by an expression?

Tags: python, ruby, haskell

Well, here is the thing:

I have the following Haskell code, this one:

```
[ (a, b, c) | c <- [1..10], b <- [1..10], a <- [1..10], a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 == c ^ 2 ]
```

Which will returns

```
[(4,3,5),(3,4,5),(8,6,10),(6,8,10)]
```

For those who aren't familiar with this, I'll explain:

- It returns a `tuple` (a,b,c), where each of these "definitions" (a,b,c) receive a list (1 up to 10) and his members are compared by the `a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 == c ^ 2 ?` expression (each member).

**How can I do the same (one line if possible) in Python/Ruby?**

P.S.:  *they are compared in lexicographical order.*

Comment: This can also be archieved by `filter (\(a,b,c) -> a^2+b^2==c^2) $ (,,) <$> [1..10] <*> [1..10] <*> [1..10]`

Comment: @isakkarlsson applicative style FTW!

Comment: Cool question. I definitely appreciate learning the Haskellish side of Python and Ruby.

Answer (score 12):

It's possible in Python with one long line and with no import.  Python's list comprehensions can be used with multiple variables:

```
>>> [ (a, b, c) for c in range(1, 11) for b in range(1, 11) for a in range(1, 11) if a*a + b*b == c*c ]
[(4, 3, 5), (3, 4, 5), (8, 6, 10), (6, 8, 10)]
```

Answer (score 11):

Ruby solution:

```
(1..10).to_a.repeated_permutation(3).select { |a, b, c| a*a + b*b == c*c }
# => [[3, 4, 5], [4, 3, 5], [6, 8, 10], [8, 6, 10]]
```

Answer (score 9):

Python solution, using [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which is equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression:

```
[(a,b,c) for c,b,a in product(range(1,11), repeat=3) if a*a + b*b == c*c]
```

Comment: `product(range(1, 11), repeat = 3)`

Answer (score 5):

A Ruby alternative without forcing identical ranges:

```
>> (1..10).to_a.product((1..10).to_a, (1..10).to_a).select { |a, b, c| a*a + b*b == c*c }
#=> [[3, 4, 5], [4, 3, 5], [6, 8, 10], [8, 6, 10]]
```

You can argue that this does not return the expected result, that's because you use c->b->a to iterate but return (a, b, c). So I am afraid in Ruby, having no list-comprehensions, we need to do something like this (map_select=map+compact):

```
>> (1..10).to_a.product((1..10).to_a, (1..10).to_a).map { |c, b, a| [a, b, c] if a*a + b*b == c*c }.compact
 #=> [[4, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5], [8, 6, 10], [6, 8, 10]]
```

Not vanilla Ruby, but using the cool library [lazylist](http://flori.github.com/lazylist/) you can write:

```
>> list { [a, b, c] }.where(:c => (1..10), :b => (1..10), :a => (1..10)) { a*a + b*b == c*c }.to_a
#=> [[4, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5], [8, 6, 10], [6, 8, 10]]
```

Comment: I prefer this variant as it reflects the original code more closely, although is longer.

Comment: I prefer this variant too; it comes closer to the original in Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

```
(for [a (range 1 11)
  b (range 1 11)
  c (range 1 11) :when (=
                        (+ (* a a) (* b b))
                        (* c c))]
  [a b c])
```

A clojure example of the same.